# How many possible four of a kind hands are there in poker?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many four of a kind hands are there? This is how I answered that:

You have $52$ options for the first card you pick. Now you have to pick four more cards: exactly three of those have to be of the same suit as the first card, and since there are only four cards per suit you only have one choice for those three cards.

The last card you can pick to be any one of the remaining cards; you've already picked four, so you have $48$ choices.

So there are $52 * 48$ four of a kind hands.

But apparently the answer is $13*48$, which makes sense if you just think of picking a suit. But what is wrong with my way of thinking that led to the wrong answer?

Comment: Suppose you start by picking $A\spadesuit$ for your first card, then pick the three remaining aces to match.  Finally, you pick a $7\heartsuit$ for the kicker.  How does this compare to you having started by picking $A\heartsuit$ for your first card, then pick the three remaining aces to match, finishing by picking $7\heartsuit$ for your kicker?  These are the same hands, no?

Comment: "*Since there are only four cards per* **suit**"  You seem to be mixing up the words "rank" and "suit."  The *ranks* are $A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,J,Q,K$.  The *suits* are $\clubsuit,\diamondsuit,\heartsuit,\spadesuit$.  There are $13$ *ranks*.  There are four *suits*.  There are thirteen cards per suit.  There are four cards per rank.

Comment: The way you are trying to answer this question makes it a lot more complicated. First we choose a card and we have 52 choices. Then we pick the second card and we have 51 choices for it, but that card we pick could either be the same rank as the original card or it might not be. We won't be forced to pick a card of the same rank until we have two cards of different ranks.

Comment: @EgoKilla that line of logic is going to lead to a count of hands where order matters.  Traditionally for this type of problem, we don't usually care about order of the cards.  (*For the purposes of probability calculations however, it generally doesn't matter if you considered order to matter or not so long as you are consistent, as both approaches lead to the same final answer*)

Comment: @JMoravitz That makes sense, it seems I was getting confused with both terminology and also just approaching the problem in an unnecessarily complicated manner. I wonder if it was just coincidence that I over-counted exactly by a factor of four. Also, what you said to EgoKilla about consistency being the main factor was eye opening for me. Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

There are $13$ choices for the value of the card (it can be $2, 3, 4, \ldots , 10,\text{J},\text{Q},\text{K},\text{A}$), and there is only one way in which you can get these four cards (their ordering doesn't matter). Once these four cards have been picked, there are $48$ options for the remaining fifth card. Therefore, there are $13\cdot 48 = 624$ possible hands.

The reason why $52 \cdot 48$ doesn't work is because it overcounts by a factor of $4$. You have the right idea, but you should realize that, when you're picking the first card, you're fixing the value that the other three cards must have. This can be done in $13$ ways (not $52$ ways) since there are only $13$ possible values.

Comment: Thank you! That helps me understand why my approach was wrong a bit better, but I'm still trying to figure out whether or not it was coincidence that I overcounted exactly by a factor of four. Could my line of thinking be taken further such that dividing by 4 would be a natural conclusion based on the logic, thus giving the right answer? In any case, thank you again!